# php get php file code contents

Tags: php, compiler-construction

I am adding a file using **require_once** in **php** just out of curiosity I want to know is it possible to get the php file code e.g

**a.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'b.php';
```

**b.php**

```
<?php
$a = 'b';
${$a} = 'c';
```

now when **require_once** the file it compiles the php code in **b.php** and executes that now what **I am looking is the php file code** e.g

```
<?php
$a = 'b';
$b = 'c';
```

I have searched a lot but couldn't find any solution thanks in advance

Comment: PHP doesn't save compiled code anywhere, it compiles on the fly.

Comment: What is "compiled PHP code"? Your sample contains just variable variable substitution and it has nothing to do with "compilation" (and so does PHP, which will do __interptetation__ to VM opcodes)

Comment: That's also not what compiling means. You just want a single language feature runtime substituted.

Comment: I mean to say the php file code

Comment: is it possible using reflection any hints

Comment: @ARIFMAHMUDRANA I don't think you will get much help with a name full of caps ... just saying.

Comment: Do you mean you want to include the file without php parsing the code? like include the file as text?

Comment: @ARIF MAHMUD RANA: do you want to get  $a and $b variables in your a.php file?

Comment: what I want is the equivalent php code of the file b.php

Comment: e.g if we replace this `<?php
$a = 'b';
${$a} = 'c';` with this `<?php
$a = 'b';
$b = 'c';` than it will work I want exact like this the equivalent code thanks

Answer (score 1):

**b.php**

```
  <?php
    $a = 'b';
    ${$a} = 'c';
```

If you want b.php file contents then use php `file_get_contents()` like this:
**a.php**

```
$bContents = file_get_contents('b.php');
$bContents = str_replace('${$a}','$b',$bContents)
print_r($bContents);
```

OUTPUT:

```
 <?php
    $a = 'b';
    $b = 'c';
```

Comment: you are missing that I want the php equivalent code say e.g if **b.php** is `<?php
$a = 'b';
${$a} = 'c';` than if I file_get_contents('b.php'); will I get `<?php
$a = 'b';` thanks for the response
$b = 'c';

Comment: @ARIF MAHMUD RANA: if you see browser source code then you will have b.php code as string. if you want ${$a} as $b then replace it.i have updated my code see output.

Comment: @ARIF MAHMUD RANA: did you try this?

Comment: I see you are going with the file you aren't going with the concept the concept is ultimately getting the equivalent code it is just a demo. what will happen if it gets a little bit complicated `<?php
$a = 'b';
${$a} = 'c';
${${$a}} = 'd';` than will with your answer will it return `<?php
$a = 'b';
$b = 'c';
$c = 'd';`

Comment: there is no other way to do it. You need to loop through your content and replace it.

Comment: I am searching for the way. In smarty we see the template is parsed to php. My concept is very much similar if there is some parser that takes php file and parse like this thanks

Answer (score 0):

Moment you do the the `require_once` your code is available to use. by code I mean whatever the variables and methods or any set of instructions you have defined in the external file.
if you need to selectively call set of instructions put them in a function inside the `b.php` and call them whenever you need.

or if you want to print any code from your `b.php` assign all instructions to a variable as a string. but i highly doubt this is your requirement

Comment: sorry you completely misunderstand the concept I want the php file code I required once thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

You would want to make b.php echo out the php code as text like so:

```
echo '<?php
        $a = "b";
        ${$a} = "c";
      ?>';
```

However, echo'ing PHP code in a file can expose this code publicly and it is a bad idea.

Comment: you are modifying **b.php** file which isn't ultimately the goal of the question thanks for the response

Comment: php is going to parse any file you "include" (or require)..  the only way to output any php code within a php "include" is to `echo` it.  I know it probably isn't the answer you wanted, but it is what it is. sorry.